# finding key with maximum value in java mapreduce

Tags: java, mapreduce

I am trying to find the key with max value but an error is generated everytime saying cannot convert text to string. This is related to java mapreduce.

> Error :
>   The method write(Text, IntWritable) in the type TaskInputOutputContext is not applicable for the arguments (String, IntWritable)

**List**:

```
994290  5  
994380  33  
994410  1  
994440  11  
995010  2  
995030  5
```

**Expected**:

```
994380  33
```

**Code**:

```
@Override
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    int max = 0;
    String keyWithMax = "";
    for (IntWritable value : values) {
        if (value.get() > max) {
            max = value.get();
            keyWithMax = key.toString();
        }
    }
    context.write(keyWithMax, new IntWritable(max));
}
```

Can you please help me in this?

Comment: Kindly check my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to do anything with `key`, you can just use it as passed in

```
@Override
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                   Context context)
                   throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int max= 0;
    for (IntWritable value : values) {
        if(value.get() > max){
          max= value.get();
        }
    }
    context.write(key, new IntWritable(max));
  }
```

Comment: Hi avigil, The above modified code is displaying the keys with minimum values. Can you please have a look into it?

Comment: This reduce step will find the max value of an individual key, you still need an additional step to find the max among all the keys.

Comment: Hi Avigil, can you please help me with some lines of code please...As i am new to java and big data it is getting a bit confusing for me...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `keyWithMax` to the `context.write()` method, which is a `String` type. It is expecting `Text()` type of data as key.

Problem is with the line `context.write(keyWithMax, new IntWritable(max));`
Change it to `context.write(new Text(keyWithMax), new IntWritable(max));`

Or better, define a global variable for output key as

```
private Text outKey= new Text();
```

And set it before writing to context

```
outKey.set(keyWithMax);
```

It is because creating a `new Text()` is more expensive than creating once and reusing. Same is the case with `new IntWritable(max)`.